# Mongoose POST request will not execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue with making a post request to MongoDB. The following request:

```
router.post("/updateReply/:id", (req, res) => {

    let id = req.params.id;

    CommentReply.findById({id}).then(comment => {
            comment.description = req.body.description;
            comment.save().then(reply => {
                res.json(reply);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(200).send(err);
        })
});
```

keeps failing with the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ id: '5e137efeb2be3d4408ce374b' }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"commentReplies\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"{ id: '5e137efeb2be3d4408ce374b' }\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": {
        "id": "5e137efeb2be3d4408ce374b"
    },
    "path": "_id"
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this, especially since my get requests works successfully each time :

```
router.get("/getReply/:id", (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;

    CommentReply.findById(id).then(comment => {
        res.json(comment);
    });       
});
```

Comment: try to rename `id` variable to be `_id` and pass it the same way as an object to `findById` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send an object to findById, send a string...

```
// not ({id})
CommentReply.findById(id)....
```

Comment: Very silly mistake by me and I simply couldn't spot it. Thanks for this you've saved me a lot of stress haha

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CommentReply.findById({id})

Try CommentReply.findById(id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use findByIdAndUpdate as below, in .then() you can implement callbacks and so for error handling in .catch()

Find more on findByIdAndUpdate here, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

```
CommentReply.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        comment.description = req.body.description;
})
    .then()
    .catch()
```